# isNaN method doesn´t return true for none

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use a random number generator for returning a random number x. Because I need x for other calculations x has to be a number. To check that I used the isNaN method. My loop should therefore run als long as x is not a Number.
However the isNaN method doesn´t seem to work appropriate since the loop sometimes (randomly) returns "NaN".
Does anybody of you guys has a smart idea why?

```
do {
  do {
    a = 2.0 * Math.random() - 1;
    b = 2.0 * Math.random() - 1;
    q = a * a + b * b;

  } while (q === 0 && q >= 1)

  p = Math.sqrt((-2 * Math.log(q)) / q);
  x =  a * p;


} while (x <= -5.4 && isNaN(x))

return x;
```

Comment: If it works the same as every other language, `isNaN` doesn't return true for anything that isn't a number. It return true for literal `NaN`. `null` isn't `NaN`, so it returns false.

Comment: `while (q === 0 && q >= 1)` - Huh? (Also, what's with all the calculations? Returning a random number between x and y is usually a one-liner. What is the actual desired output of the function?)

Comment: It may a null, 0/0 or literally anything other than a number(of course).. Do a console.log to find who....

Comment: @nnnnnn But It is `do{}while()`. one run will be there.

Comment: `while (x <= -5.4 && isNaN(x))` - How could `x` be *both* less than -5.4 *and* not a number? Both `while` conditions will always be false so if the calculation *does* produce `NaN` then yes, it will be returned. @SagarV - The fact that the first one runs once doesn't make the condition any more sensible...

Comment: Both your comments are true. first while and second while. But since it is a do-while, first execute and then it will check. Better he can remove the loops @nnnnnn because the loops are not functional and execute only one time. That is what I said. The one time.

Answer (score 0):

The code is doing exactly what you are instructing.  Your outer while expression

```
while (x <= -5.4 && isNaN(x))
```

should use a logical OR rather than AND.

If isNaN(x) == true,  x <= -5.4 == false; false && true == false.

You need to brush up on [logical operators and what they do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Answer (score -2):

Normally, isNaN() function should return True or False. But you can test it by writing this:

```
var testResult = isNaN(num)
console.log(testResult);
```

Otherwise, you can create your own abstract function by creating below:

```
function isNumber(num)
{
  return ( !isNaN(num)) : true : false );
}
```

And, you can check below:

```
var checkNumber = isNumber(var);
```

Comment: good answer. But another time. This answer didn't try to solve this question.

Comment: `var` is a reserved word afaik. Also, does this compile? What are the chained `:`s? That's a new one for me. If that's supposed to be a ternary, it's redundant.

Comment: Had to downvote since this example is far from complilable, and I suspect it's wrong as well.

Comment: @Carcigenicate - The whole function is redundant, given that calling it is more typing than just `!isNaN(num)` would've been. (Unless an `isNumber()` function is needed to pass to `.filter()` or something, which isn't the case here.) This also doesn't remotely answer the question that was asked. @rcadhikari - What do you mean "normally [it] should return true or false"? What other possible value(s) could it ever return?

Comment: @nnnnnn Ya. Was just going to make that point that dispatching on Boolean literals is useless since `!NaN(...)` already returns a Boolean. That's a personal pet-peeve of mine.